# Converting a number to hex string causes error in JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, string, hex

```
let val = dcd["value"];
console.log(val)
```

result:

```
67874000000000000n
```

Converting val to a hex string causes error:

```
let val_hex = val.toString('hex');

RangeError: toString() radix argument must be between 2 and 36
    at BigInt.toString (<anonymous>)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `toString()` method is used to convert a number to a string in a given radix (base), where the radix can be any number between 2 and 36.
In order to convert a number to hex string, use base 16.

```js
const bigIntNumber = 67874000000000000n;
const hexNumber = bigIntNumber.toString(16);
console.log(hexNumber); // "f2fada63a00000"
```